# C: Reading last n lines from file and printing them

Tags: arrays, c, char, fgets

I'm trying to read last n lines from file and then print them. To read the lines I'm using `fgets()` and it seems to work fine. However, when I try to print the last n lines that I have stored in the array, it only prints the last line n times. It seems like there is something wrong with the way I store strings in an array. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int agrc, char** agrv) {
    FILE* input;
    input = fopen(agrv[1], "r");

    int n = *agrv[2]-'0';
    int line = 0;
    char text[11];
    char** tab = malloc(1000000*sizeof(text));

    while(fgets(text, sizeof(text), input) != 0) {
        tab[line] = text;
        line++;
    }

    fclose(input);

    int jump = line-n;
    
    for(int i=jump; i<line; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", tab[i]);
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I've changed my while loop to this. However, it still doesn't work.

```
    while(fgets(text, sizeof(text), input) != 0) {
        char text2[11];
        strcpy(text2, text);
        tab[line] = text2;
        line++;
    }
```

Comment: There are many problems with the code as you show it. The dynamic allocation is one problem (do you really want to allocate around 100 MiB?), and the assignment `tab[line] = text` is another (and the main reason behind your observed problems). Or using elements of `argv` without checking `argc`. Or using `input` without checking if `fopen` failed or not.

Comment: The best help would be to go back to page 1 of the book and work through all the examples until you understand what each of them is trying to teach. Sorry, but learning can be difficult...

Comment: To solve the main problems: Open the file; Seek to the end; Get the position, which will be the size of the file; Rewind the file position; Allocate buffer of the exact size; Read into buffer; Go backward from the end of the buffer to find the "n:th" newline; Print from that location. Or something similar.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Additionally, account for the possibility of user requesting "last 9 lines" for a file containing only 3 lines... Ouch.... :-)

Comment: `"...  and it seems to work fine."` It probably isn't working fine... Have you tried to print what `fgets()` is loading on each cycle (to go beyond "seems to work")?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude "Allocate buffer of the exact size" If you want to copy the last 10 lines of a book, do you memorise the entire book?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. No, but it's simpler than having to allocate and reallocate as needed. And reading backward from the file itself is also more complicated .

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You need to learn how to allocate and reallocate (or to read backwards) *once*.

Comment: There are many many problems with your code. Let's concentrate on one. You have a bunch of pointers. A whole million of pointers. These pointers need to point at some memory. Preferably at different chunks of memory, because if they all point at the same place, why do you need a million of them? So you need a million different chunks of memory to point at. *Where does all this memory come from? Who allocates it? Who frees it when it is no longer needed?* You need to be able to answer these questions.

Answer (score 1):

`tab[line] = text;` sets `tab[line]` to point to the start of `text`. So you end up with all the `tab[i]` pointing to the same place, the start of `text`.

You need to copy each line read from the file to a different place in memory.

Comment: I've changed the code according to your answer. However, it still doesn't work. Could you please check the updated question.

Comment: @TCL Your update makes it even *worse*. You still save a pointer to the exact same array (like before), but this time the array is local inside the loop so each iteration of the loop it will end its life-time making the pointer invalid.

Answer (score 0):

It may increase your understanding if you see working code that does what you hope to achieve. Because your OP could only show 1-9 "last lines", this code doesn't try to go beyond that "meager" amount. Further, this code is meant for files whose lines "are of moderate length". It should be clear where changes can be enacted.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h> // for 'isdigit()'

// Factor processing into functions for clarity
void tail( FILE *ifp, size_t n ) {
    char text[ 9 ][ 126 + 1 + 1 ]; // 9 'rows' up to 128 bytes each
    size_t lnCnt = 0;

    while( fgets( text[ lnCnt % 9 ], sizeof text[0], ifp ) != NULL )
        lnCnt++;

    // Do the math to workout what is wanted and what's available
    if( lnCnt < n )
        n = lnCnt, lnCnt = 0;
    else
        lnCnt += 9 - n;

    // output
    while( n-- )
        printf( "%s", text[ lnCnt++ % 9 ] );

}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    // Check parameters meet requirements
    if( argc != 3 || !isdigit( argv[ 2 ][ 0 ] ) ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Usage: %s filename #lines (1-9)\n", argv[ 0 ] );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // Check functions didn't fail
    FILE *ifp = fopen( argv[ 1 ], "r" );
    if( ifp == NULL ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Cannot open '%s'\n", argv[ 1 ] );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // do processing
    tail( ifp, argv[ 2 ][ 0 ] - '0' );

    // clean up
    fclose( ifp );

    return 0;
}
```